# i amtrying to fetch dates from mysql db to fullcalender.js events

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

i have a table in my database named as employee_leaves,have fields like starting date and ending date i want to fetch those dates and display them dynamically on full calender so far i have done this
but everytimes the alert is executed alerting the error...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var calender= $('#cal').fullCalendar({

        events: {
        url:"events.php",
        type:"POST",
        error: function() {
            alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
        }
     }
        })

       });
```

this is my events.php file

```
  $sql_get_leaves="SELECT * from employee_leaves";
$query_leaves=mysql_query($sql_get_leaves);
$events-array();
$res=mysql_fetch_array($query_leaves);
    $e=array();
    $e['id']="Leave_1";
    $e['title']="Leave";
    $e['start']=$res['leave_starting_date'];
    $e['end']=$res['leave_ending_date'];
    $e['allDay']=false;
    array_push($events,$e);
    echo json_encode($events);
```

Comment: Try mysqli_ functions and upload the firebug returned error

Comment: @RajkumarR there are no mysql related errors in my code i have checked it many times

Comment: Mention the firebug error

Comment: @RajkumarR may God bless You...

Comment: @RajkumarR now i have another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code properly. For ( **=** ) you have written as ( **-** ) Change and try:-

```
$events = array();
```

And also add the success function in our javascript function.